# deeplink works when the app in background but none when it's killed

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, deep-linking, ionic-plugins

i'm using ionic deeplink plugin **ionic-plugin-deeplinks** it works fine for android, but as it didn't work on ios i forced to install another plugin **cordova-deeplink**, and **cordova-universal0links-plugin**.
package.json:

> "@ionic-native/deeplinks": "^4.16.0",
>
> "cordova-deeplink":"git+https://github.com/foneclay/cordova-universal-links-plugin.git#2.3.1",
>   "cordova-universal-links-plugin": "1.2.1"
>   so in my component.ts:

```
platform.ready().then(() => {
      if (this.platform.is('android')) {
        this.deeplinks.routeWithNavController(this.nav, {
          '/e-training/course_overview/:courseID': CourseDetailsPage,
           .......
        }).subscribe((match) => {
          console.log('Successfully routed', match);
        }, (nomatch) => {
          console.log('Unmatched Route', nomatch);
        });
      } else {
        if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
          universalLinks.subscribe('openApp', this.onAppRequest.bind(this));
          universalLinks.subscribe('openPage', this.onPageRequest.bind(this));
        }
      }
    });
```

config.xml:

```
<universal-links>
        <host event="openApp" name="example.com" scheme="https">
            <path event="openPage" url="/" />
        </host>
</universal-links>
```

everything work fine on android but in ios only works when the app still in background, when i kill the app (terminate it) and click on any link that i shared through the app it open the home page of the app , didn't go deep inside the details.

Ionic:

- ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.0.2
- Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular
- 3.9.2    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

Cordova:

- cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
- Cordova Platforms     : not available

System:

- Android SDK Tools : 25.2.5
- NodeJS            : v8.9.3
- npm               : 5.4.2
- OS                : Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

I just removed the **cordova-deeplink** and **cordova-universal-links-plugin** plugin and everything related to them: like I removed the tags `<universal-links>....</universal-links>` in config.xml
and the code in app.component.ts related to ios section and replaced them by this:

```
//this.platform.is('android') || this.platform.is('ios')
this.deeplinks.routeWithNavController(this.nav, {
  '/e-training/course_overview/:courseID': CourseDetailsPage,
     ...
  }).subscribe((match) => {
    console.log('Successfully routed', match);
  }, (nomatch) => {
    console.log('Unmatched Route', nomatch);
  });
```